# Using java.util.prefs.Preferences across multiple classes

Tags: java, preferences

I'd like to integrate java.util.prefs.Preferences into my desktop application.

I need to be able to access the user preferences from multiple classes, like this:

```
public class ClassA
{
    Preferences prefs = Preferences.userRoot();
    prefs.put("PhoneNumber", phoneNumber);

    ...
} 

public class ClassB
{
    Preferences prefs = Preferences.userRoot();
    String phoneNumber = prefs.get("PhoneNumber", "555-555-1212");

    ...
}
```

After reading the API here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html

it appears that I should use the flush() after a call to put() to insure that the changes will be reflected in future calls to get(), and I should also use sync() prior to a get(), like this:

```
public class ClassA
{
    Preferences prefs = Preferences.userRoot();
    prefs.put("PhoneNumber", phoneNumber);
    prefs.flush();

    ...
} 

public class ClassB
{
    Preferences prefs = Preferences.userRoot();
    prefs.sync();
    String phoneNumber = prefs.get("PhoneNumber", "555-555-1212");

    ...
}
```

And the documentation even seems to encourage the use of flush() at one point:

"All of the methods that modify preferences data are permitted to operate asynchronously; they may return immediately, and changes will eventually propagate to the persistent backing store with an implementation-dependent delay. The flush method may be used to synchronously force updates to the backing store."

But here's the problem:  The documentation also seems to *discourage* the explicit use of both flush() and sync():

"Several methods, like flush, have semantics that prevent them from operating if the backing store is unavailable. Ordinary applications should have no need to invoke any of these methods, which can be identified by the fact that they are declared to throw BackingStoreException."

( sync() also throws BackingStoreException )

Furthermore, none of the tutorials I've read ever use flush() or get().

I'm pretty confused by this, and I'd like to know if I should be calling flush() and get() explicitly, even though this seems to be discouraged in the documentation.